# Why is the Plotly bar chart not proportional?

Tags: python, plotly, data-analysis, streamlit

I need to show on a barchart the weight value registered each Exam Date, but the Y Axis is not proportional to the value registered. 90kg is shown as smaller than 85kg. What am I missing out? Thanks in advance!

```
# First, ensure that the "ExamDate" column is of datetime data type
filtered_dataframe["ExamDate"] = pd.to_datetime(filtered_dataframe["ExamDate"], format="%d/%m/%Y")

with column1:
    st.subheader("Name wise Weight")
    
    # Use the "ExamDate" as the x-axis and group by "ExamDate" and "Name" to display bars side by side
    fig = px.bar(
        filtered_dataframe, x="ExamDate", y="Weight", color="Name", template="seaborn"
    )
    
    fig.update_layout(barmode="group")  # Display bars side by side
    st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True, height=400)
```

[image: chart example]

Tried changing the values and formatting them, but nothing changed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While you do not give an example of the dataframe that you are using (please, do give a complete example including the data), I may guess that your "Weight" column is not numeric judging by the tick labels on the y axis appearing out of order.

Answer (score 2):

I would try converting your `weight` column to a numeric type if you haven't already:

```
filtered_dataframe['weight'] = filtered_dataframe['weight'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
```

Comment: Yep, that was it! Thank you so much :))